# Execution context in Event driven programming

Tags: events, context-switch

I am reading about event driven programming  from the book:

[Practical UML Statecharts in C/C++, 2nd Edition:
Event-Driven Programming for Embedded Systems](https://www.state-machine.com/psicc2)

On page no. xxviii Introduction , the author says:

> ...the event-driven application must return control after handling
> each event, so the execution context cannot be preserved in the
> stack-based variables and the program counter as it is in a sequential
> program. Instead, the event-driven application becomes a state
> machine, or actually a set of collaborating state machines that
> preserve the context from one event to the next in the static
> variables.

I am unable to understand why the execution context cannot be preserved in the stack-based variables and the program counter once the control is returned after handling the event?

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with how the traditional sequential programming paradigm works. Suppose that you want to blink an LED on an embedded board. A common solution would be to write a program like this (e.g., see [Arduino Blink tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/blink)):

```
while (1) { /* RTOS task or a "superloop" */
    turn_LED_on();  /* turn the LED on  (computation) */
    delay(500);     /* wait for 500 ms (polling or blocking) */
    turn_LED_off(); /* turn the LED off (computation) */
    delay(1000);    /* wait for 1000 ms (polling or blocking) */
}
```

The key point here is the `delay()` function, which waits in-line until the delay elapses. This waiting is called "blocking", because the calling program is blocked until `delay()` returns.

Please note that the Blinky program calls `delay()` in two different contexts: first time after `turn_LED_on()` and the second time after `turn_LED_off()`. Each time, `delay()` returns to a different place in the code. This means that while the program is blocked, the information about the place in the code (the context of the call) is automatically preserved.

The trivial Blinky program is very simple, but in principle a blocking function, like `delay()`, could be called from other functions each with 
complex if-else-while code. Still, `delay()` will be able to return to the exact point of the call, because the C programming language preserves the context of the call (in the call stack and the program counter).

But blocking makes the whole program unresponsive to any other events and therefore people came up with [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).

An event-driven program is structured around an [event-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). An example event-driven code could look like this:

```
while (1) { /* event-loop */
    Event *e = queue_get(); /* block when event queue is empty */
    dispatch(e); /* handle the event, cannot block! */
}
```

The main point is that the `dispatch()` "event-handler" function **cannot** call a blocking function like `delay()`. Instead, `dispatch()` can only perform some immediate action and must quickly **return** back to the event-loop. That way, the event-loop remains *responsive* at all times.

But, by returning the `dispatch()` function removes its own stack frame from the call stack. So the call stack and program counter associated with calling `dispatch()` is always the same and is useless to "remember" the execution context.

Instead, to blink the LED, the `dispatch()` function must rely on some variable (`state`) that remembers the state (on/off) of the LED. An example how you could write such `dispatch()` function is as follows:

```
static enum {OFF, ON } state = OFF; /* start in the OFF state */
timer_arm(1000); /* arm a timer to generate TIMEOUT event in 1000 ms */

void dispatch(Event *e) {
    switch (state) {
        case OFF:
            if (e->sig == TIMEOUT) {
                turn_LED_on();
                timer_arm(500);
                state = ON; /* transition to "ON" state */
            }
        break;
        case ON:
            if (e->sig == TIMEOUT) {
                turn_LED_off();
                timer_arm(1000);
                state = OFF; /* transition to "OFF" state */
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

I hope you can see that `dispatch()` implements a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine) with states ON and OFF driven by one event TIMEOUT.